# vba + Selection.Paste into outlook + control poition

Tags: vba, email, excel, outlook

What I am trying to do is copy a chart from excel into an outlook email, but after numerous searching I am struggling.

i am having trouble positioning where the chart is pasted. I want it to paste after the last line `"this is another line again "` in the body of the email. It currently pastes at the start of the email before the line `"test ... body"`

```
 Sub CopyAndPasteToMailBody3() ' this works but how do i control where it puts the chart?
        Set mailApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set mail = mailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        mail.Display
        mail.To = "A@a.com"
        mail.subject = "subject" & Now
        mail.body = "test ... body" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
                    & "this is another line " & vbCrLf _
                    & "this is another line again "
        Set wEditor = mailApp.ActiveInspector.wordEditor
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy ' chart needs to be active
        wEditor.Application.Selection.Paste

        ' mail.send
    End Sub
```

**Note**: using excel 10 on windows 7

Answer (score 4):

I have found that

```
Set wEditor = mailapp.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
```

needs to be followed by

```
wEditor.Range(0, 0).Select
```

to avoid an error sometimes when you go to paste it.

Comment: HI, why does the error you talk of occur in the first place? I was experiencing the issue and the above fixed it immediately, but I didn't fully understand the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the code put the Body on the Clipboard and Paste it:

```
    Set mailApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set mail = mailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    mail.Display
    mail.To = "A@a.com"
    mail.Subject = "subject" & Now

    Dim Clip As MSForms.DataObject
    Set Clip = New MSForms.DataObject
    Clip.SetText ("test ... body" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
                & "this is another line " & vbCrLf _
                & "this is another line again " & vbNewLine & " ")
    Clip.PutInClipboard
    Set wEditor = mailApp.ActiveInspector.wordEditor
    wEditor.Application.Selection.Paste

    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy ' chart needs to be active
    wEditor.Application.Selection.Paste
    ' mail.send
```

In this case you can assembly the mail as you want.
**MSForms.DataObject** need to have the Reference: **Microsoft Form 2.0 Object Library (FM20.DLL)**

Comment: tks, added  Microsoft Form 2.0 Object Library (FM20.DLL) by inserting a userform. info [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/482637-excel-2010-where-microsoft-forms-2-0-object-library.html)

Comment: but now getting `Run-time error ‘4605’ This method or property is not available because the document is locked for editing` any ideas?

Comment: Actually, More often then not it works I will keep an eye on it and see how it goes. tks again

Comment: just for my reference. open the file and run the macro then i get the error. save and close, run again and it works.open again run again and i get the error.

Comment: don't understand why it does not work!! have tried  this `wb.Unprotect` from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/02dd30a7-5a7d-499d-8dc2-be15a4b399d5/getting-error-this-method-or-property-is-not-available-because-the-document-is-locked-for-editing?forum=vsto)

Answer (score 0):

You can try also with another code (in this case the image are temporary saved on disk):

```
Sub CopyAndPasteToMailBody4() ' this works but how do i control where it puts the chart?
    Set mailApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set mail = mailApp.CreateItem(0)
    mail.Display
    mail.To = "A@a.com"
    mail.Subject = "subject" & Now

    Dim Stri As String
    Stri = "test ... body" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
                & "this is another line " & vbCrLf _
                & "this is another line again " & vbNewLine & " "
    ActiveChart.Export "e:\0\C1.png"
    Stri = Stri & "<img src='e:\0\C1.png'>"
    mail.HTMLBody = Stri
    ' mail.send
End Sub
```

On my PC the first code ask me some permission, with the second code no...

Comment: tks. that looks good. have to use `<br>` to get a new line `"test ... body <br>" & vbNewLine`